# How to update maxmind GeoLite2

Tags: npm, geolocation, geoip, maxmind, geolite2

It's said GeoLite2 is updated every month, so do I have to manually update GeoLite2 every month to local?

or do this with `watchForUpdate`?

```
maxmind.open('/path/to/GeoLite2.mmdb', { watchForUpdates: true });
```

Does the update take a lot of time, I don't want users get waited for a while for GeoLite2 update for just getting their location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the [update script provided by Maxmind](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoipupdate/).

Otherwise, you will have to download the file via HTTP, unpack the `.tar.gz` and replace the local file. Yes, this may take some seconds because the file is large.

Comment: I found an lite and ultra lite npm package

Comment: @Daniel.zZ what is that npm package?